# laravel 4.1 password reminders : any way of making obsolete tokens unusable?

Tags: authentication, laravel, reminders

I am currently using a ReminderController (created using `php artisan auth:reminders-controller`) in order to provide users with a password reset mechanism. I was testing the mechanism and was surprised to have the following scenario for the same user/email :

1. password request#1 (sends token#1)
2. password request#2 (sends token#2)
3. password reset using token#2 : reset with password#2. at this stage the user has successfully reset his password
4. password reset using token#1 : reset with password#1. at this stage the password has been changed to password#1, which was sort of unexpected.

I imagine this is the expected behavior on Laravel but I was hoping to have a way of cancelling other tokens (for the user) whenever a successful reset occurs.

I am hoping for either a configuration step I am unaware of or an extra code hook to plug in one of the steps...

Thanks for your help,

Tepp.

Answer (score 0):

After you reset a password, just run a function like this

```
PasswordReminder::where('email', $user->email)->delete()
```

That will clear any tokens for that user.